# Slick Slider on mouse wheel scroll code doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

So I'm trying to make the slick slider work on mouse wheel scroll too. I tried the code above but it doesn't work, can anyone help me out ?

In console I get this error: core.js:898 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slickPrev' of undefined

```
slider
  .slick({
    dots: true
  });
//Implementing navigation of slides using mouse scroll
slider.on('wheel', (function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
    $(this).slick('slickNext');
  } else {
    $(this).slick('slickPrev');
  }
}));
```

Comment: your code looks fine so there must be some other issue like an issue with your environment or how you have assigned `slider`. here is your code running fine in js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/19k3oq0c/

Comment: is there any possible way to trigger $prevArrow when mouse wheel scroll down ?

Comment: Here´s an example working, take a look: https://codepen.io/rg-the-selector/pen/LYWVZQX

In this example there are 2 sliders, one acting as nav for the other, the mousewheel applys to the first slider. The JS involved is in fact same as yours. Notice how the on wheel function is called after slick one, that´s important.